# Auto-start and Closing Apps

Tags: force-close, auto-start

My android device is rooted and its 4.4.2.

To control auto-start app, I installed Clean Master and allowed it for root access. I stopped many apps that start automatically. To control start-up app, I installed Boot Manager Xposed. Apart from these I installed other apps also for controlling auto-start and start-up app.

However, I have following concerns.

1. In spite of above, I see many apps like browsers, shopping, news,
   etc; automatically in Running Apps.
2. Whenever I close any apps, I remove them from Recent Apps also. And I keep Recent Apps empty/clean. However, most of time I see closed apps are still in Running Apps. It means those apps not closed completely.

I do End Process for all unwanted apps manually every time from Running Apps which is ridicules for me.

Till the time, I don’t call/tap any apps, I don’t want see them in Running Apps and once I close any app, I don’t want to see them again in Running Apps.

Please let me know to control them.

[image]

Comment: Android keeps some processes in background! Killing them won't help because they will be opened again by the system! You can limit background processes though.

Comment: I do understand.. Android keeps some process in background but applications for which I am talking are user applications that we download like shopping apps, news apps, etc.

Comment: Yeah even for third party apps, their processes are kept by the system for optimization purpose.

Comment: OK. What about closing apps that I explained in concern no. 2.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: How to post screenshot here? I don't see any option here.

Comment: Edit your question.

Comment: Thank you for guiding me that how upload a screenshot but I could only one screenshot. I have three screenshots that show a list of apps in Running Apps. Also I would like say, Recent Apps are blank and I didn't tap most of apps that you see in running apps.

Comment: I don't have issues with Google Play services. However you there are many services of Google Play are running. Like Hindustan Times apps, there are many other user apps services are running in background.

Comment: Please see this new article 2017/02/10 [10 most useless apps and games for Android](http://www.androidauthority.com/most-useless-apps-android-749163). Most prominent, but specifically named in the list: Clean Master (along with quote-Booster apps, Anti-Virus apps, and Task Killers-unquote)

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve? It looks like everything is working as intended here.

Answer (score 0):

Try "Prevent Running", This app will help you to prevent apps and their services running in Background services(Including system app and their services).

This app will not work With out "Xposed Famework" and "Framework Installer".

http://repo.xposed.info/module/me.piebridge.forcestopgb